# Charbonah related to destruction?

Tags: names, purim, megillat-esther, churban-destruction

Charbonah is the person who reminded Ahashverosh about the tree that Haman made to hang Mordechai on.

I realize that the names of most of the people mentioned in the Megillah are Persian. However, some of the names seem similar to Hebrew words, and IIRC, Rash"i explains the name "Memuchan". Is the name "Charbonah" related to the word "churban" meaning "destruction"? Does anyone explain the reason for his name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Medrash Esther Raba 3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37460&st=&pgnum=187) says Charvona was called Charvona as he was responsible for the Churban Bais Hamikdash.

> חרבונא מופיע פעמיים במגילה - בתחילת המגילה הוא מופיע כאחד משבעת
>   הסריסים המשרתים את פני המלך אחשרוש, ובסוף המגילה הוא מגלה לאחשורוש על
>   העץ שהכין המן. חרבונא זהו שם פרסי (א' בסופו). אומר המדרש [אסתר רבה, ג]
>   שמשמעות שמו - "אחריב ביתיה", לשון חורבן. חרבונא מייצג במלכות אחשורוש
>   את האחראי על החורבן. אין זה אלא שחרבונא היה אחד מהאנשים שהחריבו את בית
>   המקדש. לאחר מכן, במשתה אסתר הוא נושא דרוש מפואר - ועל זה הוא זכור
>   לטוב. אך יש הבדל בין שתי הפעמים שחרבונא מופיע במגילה - בסוף המגילה
>   חרבונא מופיע עם האות ה' - חרבונה. זה חורבן ובנייה, הפיכת החורבן
>   לבנייה.

Thanks to http://www.ybm.org.il/hebrew/LessonArticle.aspx?item=4571 for this answer.